# Java Compiling Error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm running into a problem while trying to compile my code:

```
D:\workspace>javac DbConnect.class
javac: invalid flag: DbConnect.class
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

This is what i get. I actually have never added any of those options and it always worked fine for me. What could i have done wrong ?

**EDIT:**

Thanks guys it has been a long day at the office :)

The code works fine when i fire it from eclipse. If i type java DbConnect.class i get this Error.

```
D:\workspace\GeoCoding\bin\de\bitmarck\bi>java DbConnect.class
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DbConnect/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DbConnect.class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: DbConnect.class.  Program will exit.
```

It works in Eclipse but it just doesn't seem to like being started manually.
There is a `main` in the class.
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: probably you're just tired... see my answer

Comment: Regarding your edit, are you specifying the classpath? Have a look at the command line options for the [Java Application Launcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html). Eclipse deals with all of that for you. If you're doing it manually then you need to take care of the classpath yourself.

Comment: @shitake83...look into my answer. You don't provide the extension while running the program, Try `java DbConnect`

Comment: So in order to start it from the command prompt, I would have to include the classpath and stuff ?? I'm trying to make it very easy four our users. It's an app that updates geocoordinates and it has to be run every couple weeks. I dont want users to deal with an endless number of instructions. I want them to type java DbConnect.class and that should be it.

Comment: @shitake83 First, take note of @Swaranga's point re: not specifying the .class on the end when calling java to run your app. It's `java DbConnect`, not `java DbConnect.class`. Then, yes - you need to specify the classpath etc. You could write a script to make it easy for your users.

Comment: Like I said you have to type `java dbConnect` and NOT `java DbConnect.class` The `.class` extension must NOT be specified when you want to execute a program. Did you even look into the answers properly? Any one of them?

Comment: omg. I think i'll have to leave the office ^^. Uhhm gosh didn't think it would be that hard to NOT use an IDE. @Swaranga yeah you are right, but i still get the same exception.

Comment: @shitake83...can you update you question. It will be easier. And BTW, it is NOT hard NOT to use an IDE. The gerenally well though of principle is to start using the command line first when we start learning and AFTER we get used to and comfortable with all the gory details of classpaths and referenced libraries etc, move to an IDE for better productivity. That way even if your IDE hides most of the complexities, you always know what is going on.

Comment: Yes Swaranga that might be the best way. But as you can see its not the case for everybody and in my case its the other way round, than what you pointed out to be the perfect way to do it. How if you point me to some information ?! That would be very nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
javac DbConnect.java
```

to compile ( the file extension is .java not .class )

or

```
java DbConnect
```

to run it, if that's what you need

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. To Compile : `D:\workspace>javac DbConnect.java`
2. To Run: `D:\workspace>java DbConnect`

Answer (score 0):

You try to compile already compiled class (it has .class extension).